# Mapping unless exception

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of `String`s representing serialized data that I want to `map` to a list of objects. I use the following code:

```
strings.map { gson.fromJson(it, Model::class.java) }
// .doOtherStuff
```

However, sometimes there is a parsing error and the stream just stop, I would like to able to recover the list up until the point of failure. For example, if the error occurs at item 7, I would like `doOtherStuff` to get the 6 items that were successfully processed.

What's the most idiomatic way to do this? I can filter the list to see if the parsing will succeed but that's an expensive operation being doing twice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can treat an exception as `null` and then filter the nulls.

```kotlin
val models = modelsInJson.mapNotNull { json ->
    try {
        gson.fromJson(json, Model::class.java) 
    } catch (ex: WhateverException) {
        // TODO: logging here?
        null
    }
}
```

Replace `WhateverException` with the correct one for the type of errors you want to handle, other errors can still stop the processing.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the performance implications of this? The list I'm using is pretty large... I realize it's will be 2N worst case but I'm wondering if the compiler optimized it somehow.

Comment: You can use `mapNotNull` instead of `map` with `filterNotNull` to reduce the complexity from 2N to N.

Comment: I believe mapNotNull would ignore values in list that are null, but they aren't. They just can't be parsed.

Comment: @SaadFarooq [`mapNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html) "returns a list containing only the non-null *results* of applying the given transform function to each element in the original collection" (*emphasis* added). That's how this answer's solution works: it transforms strings into either `Model` instances (when it can be parsed) or `null` (when it can't be parsed). This results in a `List<Model>` that is potentially shorter in length than the input collection.

Comment: @mfulton26 I've added an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55849088/238134) with `mapNotNull` to make the solution more discoverable for other users.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for seems to be a combination of `map` and `takeWhile`. You can always roll your own. e.g. The following is adapted from the sources of `mapNotNull` and `takeWhile`:

```
inline fun <T, R : Any> Iterable<T>.mapWhileNotNull(transform: (T) -> R?): List<R> {
    return mapWhileNotNullTo(ArrayList<R>(), transform)
}

inline fun <T, R : Any, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<T>.mapWhileNotNullTo(destination: C, transform: (T) -> R?): C {
    for (element in this) {
        val transformed = transform(element)
        if (transformed == null) {
            break
        } else {
            destination.add(transformed)
        }
    }
    return destination
}
```

Now you can map an iterable up to a transform invocation that results in `null` and, like [Jayson Minard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3679676/jayson-minard)'s [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519859/3255152), you can map whatever exception you need to `null`:

```
strings.mapWhileNotNull {
    try {
        gson.fromJson(it, Model::class.java)
    } catch (e: JsonSyntaxException) {
        null
    }
}
// .doOtherStuff
```